# Symmetric limit in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization

I have a question on page 655 of Peskin and Schroeder.
The second equation of (19.23) is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179474/).
But the first equation of (19.23) is still a mystery.
$$ \underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\text{symm lim}}=\left\{\frac{\epsilon^{\mu}}{\epsilon^2}\right\} =0 $$
How can we understand this?

Answer (score -1):

Look at (19.27).
$$ \bar\psi(x+\varepsilon/2)\,\Gamma\,\psi(x-\varepsilon/2) = \frac{-i}{2\pi} \mathrm{tr} \left[ \frac{\gamma^{\alpha}\epsilon_{\alpha}}{\epsilon^2} \Gamma \right]\tag{19.27} $$
where the two fermion fields are contracted.
And note the first sentence of the paragraph just below (19.27) :

> Because the contraction of fermion fields is singular as $\epsilon \to 0$, the terms of order $\epsilon$ in the last line of (19.25) can give a finite contribution.

i.e. When one put $\Gamma =I$ in (19.27), one should get a divergent quantity.
So the first expression in (19.23) is misprinted. it should be replaced by 
$$ \underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\text{symm lim}}=\Bigl\{\frac{\epsilon^{\mu}}{\epsilon^2}\Bigr\} \to \infty$$

Comment: I think this is the correct expression. Any comments will be welcomed.

Comment: By the way, the reason for posting this question is that I cannot add a comment to [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179474/). For I don't have 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: There seem to be many misprints in this section 19.1 which is not still listed in [the errata](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~mpeskin/QFT.html). See [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293924/) and perhaps more.

Comment: If you put $\Gamma=I$ in 19.27, you get zero because the trace of $\gamma^\mu$ is zero. If you put $\Gamma= \gamma^\nu$ you get the symmetric limit of $\epsilon^\nu/\epsilon^2$ which is zero because averaging $ \epsilon^\nu$ over all directions (this is what the "symmetric limit" means) of the $\epsilon$ vector gives zero also.